# How to use google reverse geocoding with react native Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to put in my application a button that when pressed return the current address of the cell phone.

The latitude and longitude I am able to return correctly, and to convert this data into an address I got to the [react-native-geocoder](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-geocoder#install) library.

My current code looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import Geocoder from 'react-native-geocoder';
 // 0.4.8

class GeolocationExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
      error: null,
    };
  }

  refresh = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
  };

  render() {
    Geocoder.geocodePosition(this.state.latitude,this.state.longitude)
    return (
      <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
        <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>

        {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}
         <Button
          style={{ marginTop: 30 }}
          onPress={() => { this.refresh(); }}
          title="Refresh"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default GeolocationExample;
```

From what I understood in `Geocoder.geocodePosition(this.state.latitude,this.state.longitude)` would be returning the address, but I did not understand how to get this data from there.

The code in the Snack: https://snack.expo.io/rJhYwaG2Z

Comment: You are using Expo, but this react-native-geocoder library requires you to tweak your XCode project on iOS and change stuff on the Android project too. Did you do that changes? I'm asking because they may require you to eject your App from Expo.

Comment: @R.Bravo Yes, I made the modifications

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You don't need a library for reverse geocoding from LatLon, you can just call Google Maps API directly like:

```
fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + myLat + ',' + myLon + '&key=' + myApiKey)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            console.log('ADDRESS GEOCODE is BACK!! => ' + JSON.stringify(responseJson));
})
```

**(remember to provide your Google Maps API Key!!)**

The result object will have all the Address Components for that LatLon.

[Example result](https://codepen.io/rbravo/pen/wQrzyK)

```
{"results":[{"address_components":[{"long_name":"540","short_name":"540","types":["street_number"]},{"long_name":"Avenida Alda Garrido","short_name":"Av. Alda Garrido","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Barra da Tijuca","short_name":"Barra da Tijuca","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"Rio de Janeiro","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"RJ","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"Brazil","short_name":"BR","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"22640-000","short_name":"22640-000","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"Av. Alda Garrido, 540 - Barra da Tijuca, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, 22640-000, Brazil","geometry":{"location":{"lat":-23.0077328,"lng":-43.315117},"location_type":"ROOFTOP","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":-23.0063838197085,"lng":-43.3137680197085},"southwest":{"lat":-23.0090817802915,"lng":-43.3164659802915}}},"place_id":"ChIJfSac_7vQmwARNiQbMrnXe4E","types":["street_address"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Apto 301","short_name":"Apto 301","types":["subpremise"]},{"long_name":"470","short_name":"470","types":["street_number"]},{"long_name":"Avenida Alda Garrido","short_name":"Av. Alda Garrido","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Barra da Tijuca","short_name":"Barra da Tijuca","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"Rio de Janeiro","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"RJ","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"Brazil","short_name":"BR","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"22621-000","short_name":"22621-000","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"Av. Alda Garrido, 470 - Apto 301 - Barra da Tijuca, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, 22621-000, Brazil","geometry":{"location":{"lat":-23.0079088,"lng":-43.3148068},"location_type":"ROOFTOP","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":-23.0065598197085,"lng":-43.3134578197085},"southwest":{"lat":-23.0092577802915,"lng":-43.3161557802915}}},"place_id":"ChIJpQ8sq77QmwARA6fRe9QZWZ0","types":["establishment","lodging","point_of_interest"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"589","short_name":"589","types":["street_number"]},{"long_name":"Avenida Alda Garrido","short_name":"Av. Alda Garrido","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Barra da Tijuca","short_name":"Barra da Tijuca","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"Rio de Janeiro","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"RJ","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"Brazil","short_name":"BR","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"22620-171","short_name":"22620-171","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"Av. Alda Garrido, 589 - Barra da Tijuca, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, 22620-171, Brazil","geometry":{"location":{"lat":-23.0081304,"lng":-43.3147502},"location_type":"ROOFTOP","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":-23.0067814197085,"lng":-43.3134012197085},"southwest":{"lat":-23.0094793802915,"lng":-43.3160991802915}}},"place_id":"ChIJr2eVq77QmwARA3U9jQNI5Z8","types":["establishment","premise"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"540","short_name":"540","types":["street_number"]},{"long_name":"Avenida Alda Garrido","short_name":"Av. Alda Garrido","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Barra da Tijuca","short_name":"Barra da Tijuca","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"Rio de Janeiro","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"RJ","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"Brazil","short_name":"BR","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"22620-171","short_name":"22620-171","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"Av. Alda Garrido, 540 - Barra da Tijuca, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, 22620-171, Brazil","geometry":{"location":{"lat":-23.0078265,"lng":-43.3151749},"location_type":"RANGE_INTERPOLATED","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":-23.0064775197085,"lng":-43.3138259197085},"southwest":{"lat":-23.0091754802915,"lng":-43.3165238802915}}},"place_id":"EkRBdi4gQWxkYSBHYXJyaWRvLCA1NDAgLSBCYXJyYSBkYSBUaWp1Y2EsIFJpbyBkZSBKYW5laXJvIC0gUkosIEJyYXppbCIbEhkKFAoSCXvIbAC80JsAEXZMHH23Zf8TEJwE","types":["street_address"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Avenida Alda Garrido","short_name":"Av. Alda Garrido","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Barra da Tijuca","short_name":"Barra da Tijuca","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"Rio de Janeiro","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"RJ","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"Brazil","short_name":"BR","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"22620-171","short_name":"22620-171","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"Av. Alda Garrido - Barra da Tijuca, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, 22620-171, Brazil","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":-23.0077138,"lng":-43.3146692},"southwest":{"lat":-23.0080912,"lng":-43.3153903}},"location":{"lat":-23.0079025,"lng":-43.3150298},"location_type":"GEOMETRIC_CENTER","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":-23.0065535197085,"lng":-43.3136807697085},"southwest":{"lat":-23.0092514802915,"lng":-43.3163787302915}}},"place_id":"ChIJe8hsALzQmwARd0wcfbdl_xM","types":["route"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"22620-400","short_name":"22620-400","types":["postal_code"]},{"long_name":"Barra da Tijuca","short_name":"Barra da Tijuca","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"Rio de Janeiro","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"State of Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"RJ","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"Brazil","short_name":"BR","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Barra da Tijuca, Rio de Janeiro - State of Rio de Janeiro, 22620-400, Brazil","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":-23.0078347,"lng":-43.3137711},"southwest":{"lat":-23.0118196,"lng":-43.3149785}},"location":{"lat":-23.0108544,"lng":-43.3146249},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":-23.0078347,"lng":-43.31302581970849},"southwest":{"lat":-23.0118196,"lng":-43.31572378029149}}},"place_id":"ChIJxyn3hb7QmwARggN-wB930Xo","types":["postal_code"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Barra da Tijuca","short_name":"Barra da Tijuca","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"Rio de Janeiro","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"State of Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"RJ","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"Brazil","short_name":"BR","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"22620-171","short_name":"22620-171","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"Barra da Tijuca, Rio de Janeiro - State of Rio de Janeiro, Brazil","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":-23.0009429,"lng":-43.2977475},"southwest":{"lat":-23.0153102,"lng":-43.3294084}},"location":{"lat":-23.0093991,"lng":-43.3173933},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":-23.0009429,"lng":-43.2977475},"southwest":{"lat":-23.0153102,"lng":-43.3294084}}},"place_id":"ChIJ2zZsIqPQmwARquMCy3yno4Q","types":["postal_code","postal_code_prefix"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Barra da Tijuca","short_name":"Barra da Tijuca","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"Rio de Janeiro","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"State of Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"RJ","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"Brazil","short_name":"BR","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Barra da Tijuca, Rio de Janeiro - State of Rio de Janeiro, Brazil","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":-22.9642374,"lng":-43.2844897},"southwest":{"lat":-23.0228827,"lng":-43.45027049999999}},"location":{"lat":-23.0003709,"lng":-43.36589499999999},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":-22.9642374,"lng":-43.2844897},"southwest":{"lat":-23.0228827,"lng":-43.45027049999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJXf62J0ramwARTg-e2NH2w2M","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"Rio de Janeiro","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"State of Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"RJ","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"Brazil","short_name":"BR","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Rio de Janeiro - State of Rio de Janeiro, Brazil","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":-22.7460201,"lng":-43.0990395},"southwest":{"lat":-23.0828927,"lng":-43.7965385}},"location":{"lat":-22.9112301,"lng":-43.4452148},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":-22.7460201,"lng":-43.0990395},"southwest":{"lat":-23.0828927,"lng":-43.7965385}}},"place_id":"ChIJC7UkQv5-mQAR7llshDwliPk","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"Rio de Janeiro","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"Rio de Janeiro","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"State of Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"RJ","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"Brazil","short_name":"BR","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Rio de Janeiro, State of Rio de Janeiro, Brazil","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":-22.7460327,"lng":-43.0969042},"southwest":{"lat":-23.0822288,"lng":-43.7950599}},"location":{"lat":-22.9068467,"lng":-43.1728965},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":-22.7460327,"lng":-43.0969042},"southwest":{"lat":-23.0822288,"lng":-43.7950599}}},"place_id":"ChIJW6AIkVXemwARTtIvZ2xC3FA","types":["locality","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"State of Rio de Janeiro","short_name":"RJ","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"Brazil","short_name":"BR","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"State of Rio de Janeiro, Brazil","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":-20.7632054,"lng":-40.9568207},"southwest":{"lat":-23.3689318,"lng":-44.8893205}},"location":{"lat":-22.9098755,"lng":-43.2094971},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":-20.7632054,"lng":-40.9568207},"southwest":{"lat":-23.3689318,"lng":-44.8893205}}},"place_id":"ChIJw4riypQYmAAR0IMFwRrDSQM","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Brazil","short_name":"BR","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Brazil","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":5.2717863,"lng":-28.650543},"southwest":{"lat":-34.0891,"lng":-73.9828169}},"location":{"lat":-14.235004,"lng":-51.92528},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":5.2717863,"lng":-28.650543},"southwest":{"lat":-34.0891,"lng":-73.9828169}}},"place_id":"ChIJzyjM68dZnAARYz4p8gYVWik","types":["country","political"]}],"status":"OK"}
```

Comment: your solution also worked for me.but I want to retrieve city and state from response.how did I get that?

Comment: You have to iterate on the `address_components` of the response and find the `type` that you want. To learn more about Google Address Components and their Types, check: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types

In my case I'm interested in brazilian addresses, so the following code worked for state name:
```var stateName = responseJson.results[0].address_components.filter(x => x.types.filter(t => t == 'administrative_area_level_1').length > 0)[0].short_name;```
for City Name I used the `administrative_area_level_2` 
(could not post full code in this reply)

Comment: can we fetch JSON object of areas around my location ?

Comment: @devanshsadhotra what do you mean by areas? just use the Latitude and Logitude of your location and check what Google returns. [Example](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=-23.0078349,-43.3149783)

Comment: @R.Bravo i meant to say , how can i get data around my latLang with in a particular radius

Comment: @devanshsadhotra you can try the [Google Places Search on the Nearby Search section](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) or [FourSquare API](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/search) for finding nearby venues or [Facebook Places Search](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/web/search). They are all LatLng based searches that return data around that location. Good luck!

Comment: hi @R.Bravo, I am getting response like.....
{
    "error_message": "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 175.101.128.25, with empty referer",
    "results": [],
    "status": "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

what should i do? Please give me solution for this.

Comment: @Harika , you need to provide your [Google Maps API Key](https://developers.google.com/console). I have updated the answer with the resulting JSON and a link to a codepen.io example.

Comment: @R.Bravo I have `Maps SDK for Android` enabled , and I have a none restricted API  key,  but still I get error `This API project is not authorized to use this API.` and `REQUEST_DENIED`, what should I do!

Comment: @Yasir This example I gave on my answer does not use the `Maps SDK for Android`, it's a simple `HTTP GET`, so you may have to enable the `Maps 
Geolocation API`. You just have to enable the `Maps SDK for Android` if you're using the [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps) component

Comment: @R.Bravo I actually had to enable ```Geocoding API``` for that, enabling ```Geolocation API``` didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6):

There is [Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(location)](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location/#locationreversegeocodeasynclocation) for expo app.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your answer to include an explanation of the code you included. This will improve the quality of your answer, and make it easier for people to find it and upvote it :)

Answer (score 4):

Undestanding your requirement is completed with google api answer,

But now it is not for free, one cannot use more than free limit other than billing google account.

So, if you are or anyone working with [React-Native-Geocoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geocoder) , you can implement it like this:

```
var pos = {
  lat: 40.7809261,
  lng: -73.9637594
};

Geocoder.geocodePosition(pos).then(res => {
    alert(res[0].formattedAddress);
})
.catch(error => alert(error));
```

Comment: React-Native-Geocoder only works on ejected apps. Won't work on expo.

Comment: it is not working for some devices but for some device it is working

Comment: Also, that library requires you to put the API key as a string and is not very secure.

Answer (score 2):

If using expo;

```
import * as Location from 'expo-location'

getAddress = async () => {
    let {status} = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync(); // Get the location permission from the user and extract the 'status' key from it.
    if(status !== 'granted') {

        alert('permission denied!');
        return;
    }
    let address = Location.reverseGeoCodeAsync({lat, lng});

}
```

More details here;

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location/#locationreversegeocodeasynclocation