# Get location name from the latitude and longitude in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geolocation, navigator, react-native-maps

At present i'm getting latitude and longitude form `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success,error,{})` in react-native.
But I want to display users location. How can i do that without using google Geocoding API?

Comment: Could you include the component you have written so far when trying to display the user's location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably a reverse geocoding service (i.e. convert lonlat to street address). If so, you can make use of [Google Maps Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)

Possible duplicate of [Use Geocoder to return the device address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590698/use-geocoder-to-return-the-device-address)