# using react native how to get current locations city name?

Tags: react-native

Hi im using react native and I want to get my current locations city name can anyone help me with this issue?? I dont get the response at all. I have already tried...

**Code:**

```
 componentDidMount(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          (position) => {
            try {
                Geocoder.geocodePosition({ position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude }.then(res =>
                  console.log(res);
             } catch(err) {
               console.log(err);
             }
           },
           (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
           { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000 },
         );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Native did not support Inverse Geocoding (from location to administrative information). Check this answer : [Use Geocoder to return the device address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590698/use-geocoder-to-return-the-device-address)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```js
if (results[0]) {
  var add= results[0].formatted_address;
  var  value=add.split(",");
  count=value.length;
  city=value[count-3];
  x.innerHTML = "city name is: " + city;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can use OpenStreetMap like this

```
fetch(
      `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=${your latitude}&lon=${your longitude}`,
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log({data});
        // Extract city and country information from the response
        const city =
          data.address.city ||
          data.address.town ||
          data.address.village ||
          data.address.hamlet;
        const country = data.address.country;
        console.log(city);
      })

      .catch(error => {
        // Handle errors
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
```